# Studentized residuals when I have an observed and predicted value in a dataframe without a model in Python?

Tags: python, residuals, statsmodels

I have data that contains observed and predicted values in a dataframe - thus the residual can be calulated.
But, how can I calculate and plot Studentized Standardized Residuals without building a model?

| observed | Predicted |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1 | 1.5 |
| 6.0 | 5.7 |
| 2.8 | 2.7 |
| 9.2 | 8.8 |
| 1.9 | 2.0 |
| 5.0 | 5.1 |

I understand this can be done in statsmodel, however this requires a model to be built first.

````
import statsmodels.api as sm

#Fit linear model to any dataset
model = sm.OLS(Y,X)
results = model.fit()

#create instance of influence
influence = results.get_influence()

#leverage (hat values)
leverage = influence.hat_matrix_diag

#Cook's D values (and p-values) as tuple of arrays
cooks_d = influence.cooks_distance

#standardized residuals
standardized_residuals = influence.resid_studentized_internal

#studentized residuals
studentized_residuals = influence.resid_studentized_external
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_residual we find that studentized residuals $t_i$ are defined using the *leverage* $h_{ii}$
$$
t_i =\frac{\hat{\epsilon}_i}{\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{1 -h_{ii}}}
$$
where $h_{ii}$ is the $i$th diagonal element of the hat matrix $H=X(X^T X)^{-1}X^T$. Just knowing the observed and predicted values is not enough; you'll also need $X$.

Comment: In the OLS (homoscedastic residuals) we can also use "Internally studentized residuals" that uses MSE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_residual#Internal_and_external_studentization (statsmodels has both for OLS), Everything else needs X as stated.

Comment: @Josef Can you elaborate? My understanding of the section of the article that you link is that there are two different ways to compute $\hat{\sigma}$ ("internal" and "external", as you write), but either method will still need $h_{ii}$ to compute the studentized residual $t_i$. Are you referring to $t_i = \frac{\hat{\epsilon}_i}{\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{(n-1)/n}} $? The description of the second form of $t_i$ is sparse, and I'm not sure what the wiki is trying to say about this alternative $t_i$ that doesn't involve $h_{ii}$. Is this second $t_i$ a special case that arises for an OLS model?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. You are right, the diagonal of the hatmatrix is still required. I remembered this wrong and did not read carefully enough. (Without the hii part it would be standardized or Pearson residuals.)